# Python mysql connector insert with %s

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I'm trying to append a set containing a number into my MySQL database using the Python MySQLConnector. I am able to add data manually, but the following expression with **%s** won't work. I tried several variations on this, but nothing from the documentation seems to work in my case.  The table was already buildt as you can see:

```
#Table erstellen:
#cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE anzahlids( tweetid INT  )''')
```

Here is my code and the error:

```py
print len(idset)
    id_data = [
        len(idset)
    ]
    print id_data
    insert = ("""INSERT INTO anzahlids (idnummer) VALUES (%s)""")
    cursor.executemany(insert, id_data)
    db_connection.commit()
```

> "Failed processing format-parameters; %s" % e)
>   mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Failed processing format-parameters; argument 2 to map() must support iteration

Comment: oops. Worng table. the right one would be:

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE anzahlids(
                       idnummer INT  )''')

in thecode it's done right.

Comment: Please post an example of the data in idset

Comment: idset is a list of ids. Those ids are numbers. But I want to insert `len(idset)` into the db.

Comment: The insert statement does not match the table definition. See the examples in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is an example that worked on my machine.

```
import MySQLdb
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="stackoverflow", passwd="", db="stackoverflow")
cursor = db.cursor()
try:
    sql = 'create table if not exists anzahlids( tweetid int ) ; '
except:
    #ignore
    pass

sql = ("""INSERT INTO anzahlids (tweetid) VALUES (%s)""")
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
length = [len(data)]
cursor.executemany(sql,length)
db.commit()
```

if idset is a single value you can use

```
sql = ("""INSERT INTO anzahlids (tweetid) VALUES (%s)""") % len(idset)
cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that produces:
`raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[100])' at line`

But we seem to be getting nearer...

Comment: My mistake ... I changed the answer to reflect the type of parameter needed by cursor.execute many.

Comment: argh, now it's: 
`values.append(fmt % self._process_params(params))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

But thanks again!

Comment: Please post a printout of idset

Comment: idset is a list of ids. Those ids are numbers. But I want to insert `len(idset)` into the db.

Comment: Inserting the len( of the set ) ... why ?.
FYI - This is an error in the insert sql.

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but I would like to post some nicer code. Also, the original question was using MySQL Connector/Python.

The use of executemany() is wrong. The executemany() method expects a sequence of tuples, for example, [ (1,), (2,) ].

For the problem at hand, executemany() is actually not useful and execute() should be used:

```
cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS anzahlids")
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE anzahlids (tweetid INT)")

some_ids = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
cur.execute("INSERT INTO anzahlids (tweetid) VALUES (%s)",
            (len(some_ids),))
cnx.commit()
```

And with MySQL Connector/Python (unlike with MySQLdb), you have to make sure you are committing.

(Note for non-German speakers: 'anzahlids' means 'number_of_ids')